# Xcode4 "Build Finished" HUD

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, xcode4, hud

I'm searching for a library which implements something like Xcode 4's HUD which displays when a build is finished and such things.

Can someone give me a link or some hints how to implement it?

To clarify it, I'm searching for something like [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD)

Please don't suggest Growl, it's not appropriate for my utilisation.

---

To clarify it: I'm searching for a **Mac OS X** (Cocoa/Quartz) library, not for iOS.

Comment: How isn't it? The Bezel display that comes with Growl is very similar in appearance to the “Build Finished”/“Build Failed” pop-up. What are you looking to do with this in your application that rules out Growl?

Comment: Here is similar question (answered):
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5542147/how-to-create-transparent-notification-window

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any libraries, but it would be fairly straightforward to do it yourself. Create a borderless, non-opaque, floating window and set your own custom NSView subclass as its content view.

You can then use Cocoa's excellent drawing classes to draw the thing. For example `[NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect]` will make a rounded rectangle very easily, then you can fill it with a transparent grey and composite some text and an image with shadows  and so on, in a few lines of code.

It's a bit of work, but maybe not as much as you might think.

Comment: `Cocoa With Love` has a tutorial on creating custom shaped windows. So 0.5f alpha and bezier path of rect with rounded corners should do the trick.

Answer (score -1):

[ATMHud](http://www.atomcraft.de/2011/03/07/atomhud/) may fit your needs ([source](https://github.com/atomton/ATMHud)).

Comment: Uhm, I'm searching for an Mac OS X Library, not for iPhone.