# How to create transparent notification window?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm not sure of the correct name, but I am wondering how to create (in Objective-C) a transparent notification "window/panel", such as is shown when you change the volume intensity, or keyboard illumination, or display brightness. I want to put my own icon/text on it, for my own notification.
I don't know the words to Google for, so I'm asking here.
Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Matt Gemmell's [RoundedFloatingPanel component](http://mattgemmell.com/source#roundedfloatingpanel) on his [sample code page](http://mattgemmell.com/source) may do just what you're looking for.

Answer (score 5):

After looking into using the solutions provided by the other two given answers, I found that they would not work for my purposes. So, I wrote up my own library:

### [BHBezelNotification](https://github.com/BlueHuskyStudios/BHBezelNotification/)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[Growl](http://growl.info/) is a widely-used implementation of this. By default, it doesn't look exactly like the system overlays, [though it is skinnable](http://growl.info/screenshots.php) - you probably want the Bezel notification:

[image]

See the [Growl Developer Documentation](http://growl.info/documentation/developer/) for more.