# Creating widgets with C++/Obj-C?

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, macos, widget

I want to create a widget in Mac OS X that exists on the desktop background rather than the dashboard. The widget will be interactive (the widget will be able talk through text boxes when the user clicks on it, similar to Clippy) and I need it to be floating (always been on top of all windows). The widget should also be able to be flexible- by this I mean it can change shapes (i.e. how Clippy always moves). It should almost be like a character from a game on the desktop.

I have absolutely not idea how to do this, nor do I could I find any resources that instructed me how to.

Does anyone know how I could create an interactive widget on the desktop background on all major versions of Mac OS X (i.e. Snow Leopard, Lion) that floats using either C++ or Obj-C? (C++ is much more preferable)

Comment: How about this? You help me with the question and I create one with a stripper just for you. Allright?

Comment: great — here my help: search for "borderless Windows", "HUD"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5542147/how-to-create-transparent-notification-window

Comment: Wow, why were 2 of my comments deleted?

Comment: I didn't delete your comments. Someone must have flagged them. By the way, post your comment as an answer so I can select it as best answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Borderless Windows, and HUDs can be used to simulate a widget by creating a transparent, floating window.

For more info, refer to: [How to create transparent notification window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5542147/how-to-create-transparent-notification-window)