# A toast look like apple style on macOS

Tags: macos, cocoa, toast

I wonder if there is an official function provided by Apple to make a toast (or something similar) such as the following screenshot?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uwcb4.png]

Comment: See [How to create transparent notification window?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5542147/how-to-create-transparent-notification-window), [How to make a smooth, rounded, volume-like OS X window with NSVisualEffectView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26518520/how-to-make-a-smooth-rounded-volume-like-os-x-window-with-nsvisualeffectview/29386935#29386935), [Cocoa Grey Message Overlay](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11969009/cocoa-grey-message-overlay) and Google 'BezelServices'.

Comment: you save my day :D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create transparent notification window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5542147/how-to-create-transparent-notification-window)

Comment: A similar question is also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26109701/create-a-temporary-hud-popup-notification-in-cocoa-app).