# macOS alert window in Swift

Tags: swift

Is it possible to create a window/panel like the one which appears when you run a Xcode project. This type of windows appear through out macOS, but I can't seem to find out what they are called.
Here are examples:

[image]

[image]

Comment: On other system, they are called *toast*. They don't seem to have a special name on macOS.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43290055/a-toast-look-like-apple-style-on-macos https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5542147/how-to-create-transparent-notification-window https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26518520/how-to-make-a-smooth-rounded-volume-like-os-x-window-with-nsvisualeffectview/29386935#29386935